# iSpring content on client's website is timing out, what should I look into?

Tags: php, session, timeout, lms, ispring

I have a client who uses iSpring to export zip files of domain restricted presentations for use on a relatively simple custom built PHP/Javascript LMS site, however he's recently encountered issues with longer presentations seemingly timing out or losing connection to the iSpring servers after 25 minutes or so and displaying "Unable to load content, please login to view!" on any subsequent presentations on other pages that attempt to load.

iSpring hasn't been much help and basically says it isn't their problem, despite the error being output by their content. Apparently this only affects presentations exported as zip files, and not the basic embedded versions. Any ideas about what I should be looking into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out the problem was due to the PHP session timeout defaulting to 1440 seconds (which matched the time that the client said it was taking for the problem to occur).

I tried:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);
session_set_cookie_params(3600);
```

But it seems that the server the site is on might be overriding those settings, **so I made a simple ajax call that writes to a session variable** every minute to keep the session alive when a lesson is running.